# What partitions can I share between different flavors of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, kubuntu, partitioning

I want to play with some of the different flavors of Ubuntu, i.e. Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.  I know I can share `/home`.  However, can I share `/usr`, `/boot`, or even `/bin` and `/var`. So that all flavors are working with the same programs and settings as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Ubuntu flavours are mostly Ubuntu with different desktop environments.

To try different desktop environments it is not necessary to have separate Ubuntu installations. You can safely install several desktop environments on the same Ubuntu installation.

To install a new desktop environment you can follows the instructions in this askUbuntu Q&A: 
[What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/22537)

For example you can install Gnome-Shell by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

So to answer your question: you can share all partitions between different Ubuntu flavors.